# Phpunit error: You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the BrowserKit component is not available

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Hello I'm trying to run a php unit test but it not working correct. I'm getting somehow this error:

LogicException : You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the BrowserKit component is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/browser-kit".

The test itself is really really basic so I'm pretty sure its the configuration itself which causes this problem.

This is my test case:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Service;

use App\Payment\PaypalService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PaypalServiceTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testGetApiContext(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        /** @var PaypalService $paypal */
        $paypal = $client->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('test.PaypalService');

        $test = $paypal->getApiContext();
    }
}
```

This is my phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/5.7/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="0"/>
        <env name="APP_SECRET" value="s$cretf0rt3st"/>
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1"/>

        <env name="USER_ID_CUSTOMER_CARE" value="user" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!-- For Code Coverage -->
    <logging>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml"/>
    </logging>


    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/Migrations</directory>
                <file>src/Kernel.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener"/>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

And this is my services_test.yml:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    public: true
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  test.logger: '@logger'
  test.PaypalService: '@App\Payment\PaypalService'
```

And here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the bootstrap.php:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

// Check if there are fixture files
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/Resources/fixtures')
    && (new Finder())->files()->in(__DIR__.'/Resources/fixtures')->name(
        '*.yml'
    )->hasResults()) {
    echo 'Loading fixtures...';
    passthru('php "'.__DIR__.'/../bin/console" hautelook:fixtures:load --env=test');
    echo ' Done'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I used the symfony skeleton template for creating the project and followed the instructions symfony is giving for testing but always ending in this error.

So what is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried installing the `test-pack` with `composer require --dev test-pack`? It includes the phpunit-bridge and some other dependencies like the browser-kit (which is used by the WebTestCase), dom-crawler and css-selector, which are required for functional tests.

Comment: Alternatively you can check out the [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/test-pack/blob/master/composer.json#L8) in the package repository to see which other dependencies you will need, if you want to add them manually

Comment: I installed now the test-pack but still get the same error.

Comment: Could you post the content of `tests/bootstrap.php`? Does it include the `vendors/autoload.php`?

Comment: I updated the posting above. Yes the bootsrap.php is including the vendors/autoload.php

Comment: That is odd. Are you sure the library is in the vendor folder? Could you remove the folder, run `composer install` and then check the list if browser-kit was installed? Also, can you show the full class name for WebTestCase, there are multiple instances of that class if I remember correctly. It should be `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase`.

Comment: I removed the whole vendor dir, runned composer install and checked the webtastcase class. Everything looks normal. The composer install didn't throw any errors and the webtestcase is the correct one. I've updated the posting to show. Also this happens to me onlye with the new symfony version 4.2.3. Projects that run on 4.1 are still good and the testing works there

Comment: I have the same problem, but only if i try to run [infection](https://github.com/infection/infection). using Phpunit doesnt returns the error.

Comment: Problem solved. Was a infection configuration problem

Comment: Yes mine also. I hate this configuration stuff :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **phpunit.xml** file, check the value of the APP_ENV environment variable. In my case, the symfony/framework-bundle section contained the value "*dev*" instead of "*test*".